# KBRS Shower Base Install

Tags: bathroom, shower

Soon I'm going to be installing a 40" KBRS neo-angle shower base. The flooring is very sound (23/32" t&g plywood glued and stapled on 16" centered 2x10's), but on the floor below a partition was squeezed in that raised a 2x10, that's near the back of the shower, enough to make the floor about a 1/4" low at the farthest side of the shower base.

Does anyone have any suggestions for what I should do with this?
Thanks,
Rand

Comment: Assuming the low 2 x 10 is below the plywood subfloor and cannot be furred up, you will need to shim up the shower base along that entire low side to get it as level as possible. An alternative would be to float cement across the area to make it level.

Comment: Hi Jimmy Fix-It,

Comment: Are you familiar with KBRS bases? You adhere them to the floor with thin set. Do you think the thin set could span the gap and support the base?

Comment: I would not try to float the thin-set that thick during pan install. Better to scribe a line (on wall studs or bottom plate) and float the area level with mortar first and let it set. Then apply thin-set as directed for pan install.

Comment: I have done this many times, use a level to scribe a line from the level part of the floor to the back (low) wall/area, on both sides. Then apply mortar (I guess you could use thin-set but I use fine sand mixed with portland cement), starting at the lowest area, and float it out toward the level floor area, tapering from thick to thin to nothing.